# How would you translate the "ehhhhhh" interjection from Spanish to English?

Tags: translation, interjections

For some reason, spanish speaking people (or at least argentines) when we hesitate before speaking we say "ehhhhh" (you can hear an example of the use here: [ehhh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5rrtENGGak)) which is something that might be said involuntarily . How would you translate this interjection to English? (I'm not even sure if it qualifies as an interjection or it's another kind of word).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the interjection ***uh***:

Cambridge defines it as:

> the written form of the sound people sometimes make when they pause in speaking, thinking of what to say next or how to say it

Wiktionary says:

> **uh**
>
> interj. Expression of confusion or uncertainty.
>   interj. Space filler or pause during conversation.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it's an interjection. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) also calls it a "hesitation marker".

The two that came to mind for me were *uh* and *um*:

> - [uh](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uh) exclamation
>     uk ​ /ɜː/ /ʌ/ us ​ /ɜː/ /ʌ/
>     used in writing to represent the sound that people sometimes make when they are thinking what to say next:
>     *It's not too far - it's about, uh, five miles from here.*
> - [um](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/um) exclamation
>     uk ​ /əm/ us ​ /əm/
>     used in writing to represent the sound that people make when they are pausing or deciding what to say next:
>     *"What do you think of this jacket?" "Um, I don't know if I like the colour."
>     "So what did you talk about?" "Um, I don't remember."*
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

There are certainly others, like *er*, but I think these two are most common in my experience (US). I know I'd use *uh* as inelegantly as the man in the video used *eh*.